# Catching Backspace on Chrome & Firefox is Different

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, keypress, backspace

I am trying to make a console like application, so I am catching all the keypress on the window and do related stuff with them(not important). Problem is at backspace. I have the following code:

```
$(window).bind("keypress",function(e){
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if ( code == 8) {
            a = $("#console").html();
            $("#console").html(a.substring(0,a.length-1));
            currentCommand = currentCommand.substring(0,currentCommand.length-1);           
            e.preventDefault();
        }
```

However, in Firefox, contents of the `#console` is deleted but Chrome does not execute the code above. I need a cross-browser compatible solution. What am I missing?

**ADDITION:**

If I use keydown/keyup instead of keypress, I am unable to detect if the characeter was 'A' or 'a' it always returns 'A'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript e.keyCode doesn't catch Backspace/Del in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084715/javascript-e-keycode-doesnt-catch-backspace-del-in-ie)

Comment: Yes, not an exact duplicate, but the question is answered there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this. IE doesn't fire keypress for those special keys. Perhaps it's the same with some of the other browsers.

[Javascript e.keyCode doesn't catch Backspace/Del in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084715/javascript-e-keycode-doesnt-catch-backspace-del-in-ie)

Comment: if i make: `$(window).bind("keydown",function(e){
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  console.log(code);`

It always gets me caps characters such as it is alwayws 65 whether I press A or a

Comment: Perhaps you can try to see whether the SHIFT button was pressed? Like explained in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125727/how-to-differeniate-capital-letters-from-lower-ones-in-onkeydown-event-handler-m

Comment: No, I'M sure SHIFT was not pressed