# text field accepting floating number works fine in chrome not in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a function in js which accepts only floating number, in which regex of floating number is being tested

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".validate-foating-value").keypress(function (e) {
         if (!/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/.test($(e.target).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

its working fine in chrome in Firefox as well but problems I am facing through Firefox are

- backspace not working
- arrow keys not working
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow keys</kbd> for selection and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> not working

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b85k3zbh/).

any other work around for **FLOATING** numbers?

Comment: Why do you concatenate `String.fromCharCode(e.which)` before performing the validation? I guess when you press those special keys, this is returning something that doesn't match the regexp.

Comment: @Barmar i checked it out in debugging mode - before concatenating ` String.fromCharCode(e.which) ` , i had pressed a key but `$(e.target).val()` had nothing in it, but i actually pressed the key, then I check that i am having value in `e.which` then to overcome it i appended it in `$(e.target).val()`

Comment: In Chrome, editing keys like backspace don't trigger the `keypress` event, in Firefox they do.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569138/catching-backspace-on-chrome-firefox-is-different for example

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right, and that's why i am suffering now, I wonder why all browser do not have same behavior , why they have different js engines.

Comment: Seems like a Firefox bug to me. But the `keypress` event is deprecated, so you generally should avoid it. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".validate-foating-value").keypress(function (e) {
    var keyCode =  e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which ? e.which : e.charCode;

     if (!/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/.test($(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(keyCode)) && keyCode!=8) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

Please let me know if it works for you.

Thanks

Comment: I think we need to hack something like above for backspace, you can add other keys code in the condition and it will work.

Comment: yeah I am trying something like that for now, but something inside me is saying its not the right way but a good trick, isn't it?

Comment: Yea, this will resolve your issue, but I don't think there is any simple way, might be next versions of FF will support it :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed your Javascript/JQuery code to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".validate-foating-value").bind('input propertychange', function () {
      if (!/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/.test($(this).val())) {
          var currentVal = $(this).val();
          $(this).val(currentVal.slice(0,-1));
      }
  });
});
```

There is one issue with `keypress` that's documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30108293/2314737), namely this event is not consistently fired across browsers (for instance backspace does not trigger a `keypress` on Chrome).

I tried using `keyup` in place of `keypress` but I couldn't figure out how to detect the fact that the keyboard event was producing some input. I thought of using the [JQuery `.change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) on the input box but this event is not fired every time a key is pressed but only when the elements loses focus.

So in the end I I found a solution in the accepted answer to  [Validate html text input as it's typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205164/validate-html-text-input-as-its-typed)

Please let me know if this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/b85k3zbh/10/