# How to differentiate capital and lower letters with caps lock

Tags: javascript

I have trouble to differentiate capital and lower case letters if `Caps Lock` is **ON** or **OFF**.

I tried [This Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125727/how-to-differentiate-capital-letters-from-lower-ones-in-onkeydown-event-handler) but it's not determine `Caps Lock`.

For e.g. if i press small `a` OR capital `A` with `Caps Lock On` it returns same output.

Thanks for help !

Comment: You may missed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript

Comment: Your keyboard has a "capital A" key?

Comment: @Bergi yes, if `Caps Lock` is on.

Comment: @Md.KhairulHasan i tried but it is not working check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jaydeep_Mor/4L63e3zv/8/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `key` property of the `event` object:

If the `CapsLock` is on, `event.key='A'`, and if it off `event.key='a'`

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  console.log(event.key);
});
```

You can use `keyup` or `keydown` events also, it is the same.

Comment: Appreciate ! thanks now i get pressed key using `event.key` property.